# Compare a row having comma separated string to a row in another table, sort it and then Insert the row into a third table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have two tables in MSSQL Server me which looks like below

Table 1: A Table which has comma separated values in Col2

```
--------------------------------------------------
|   S. No   |   Col1    |   Col2    |   Col3    |
--------------------------------------------------
|   1   |   AAAA    |A2,A1,C2,B2,C1|    X1  |
--------------------------------------------------
|   2   |   BBBB    |   B2  |   X2  |
--------------------------------------------------
|   3   |   CCCC| B2,C2,C1,D1, B1|  X3  |
--------------------------------------------------
|   4   |   DDDD    |   C1  |   X4  |
--------------------------------------------------
|   5   |   EEEE    |C2,C1,D1   |   X5  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Table 2: Priorities are listed in table 2

```
----------------------------------------
|      Priority |   Col1    |
---------------------------------------- 
|   1   |   D1  |
----------------------------------------
|   2   |   D2  |
----------------------------------------
|   3   |   B1  |
----------------------------------------
|   4   |   C2  |
----------------------------------------
|   5   |   C2  |
----------------------------------------
|   6   |   B2  |
----------------------------------------
|   7   |   A1  |
----------------------------------------
|   8   |   A2  |
----------------------------------------
```

Expected Output: Create a third table such that,Based on the priority in Table two, the output table should have only the highest priority value in Col2 as shown below

```
--------------------------------------------------
|   S. No   |   Col1    |   Col2    |   Col3    |
--------------------------------------------------
|   1   |   AAAA    |   C2  |   X1  |
--------------------------------------------------
|   2   |   BBBB    |   B2  |   X2  |
--------------------------------------------------
|   3   |   CCCC    |   D1  |   X3  |
--------------------------------------------------
|   4   |   DDDD    |   C1  |   X4  |
--------------------------------------------------
|   5   |   EEEE    |   D1  |   X5  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why on Earth did you tag with Excel and MySQL?

Comment: Updated the relevant tags !

Comment: Don't store multiple values in a single column.

Comment: We get the comma separated values with '|' as column delimiter from a text feed file. Using an SSIS packages, we load the data in text file into the table 1.

Comment: So, there's you're problem. You're using an ETL tool to import the data but you forgot to do the T. *Transform* the data so that you no longer have *anything* separated values stored in a single column - use a separate table that stores a row per value and references back to table 1 (for the other columns)

Comment: We have more than 1 million records in the feed file. If i transform to a row per value, it goes beyond 10 Million records and takes hours to load into table 3

Comment: The problem is though, until you separate the values, you can't apply the tools the SQL Server provides to help with speeding up queries - such as indexes - or in the alternative, transform the data into *xml* - the other data type built into SQL Server *designed* to hold multiple values, and which also has support for indexes. Either way though, storing the data in strings (a data type not designed for holding/processing multiple values) is your first bottleneck to achieving efficiency.

Comment: Initially we thought of the same approach, but backed off suspecting the performance issues ! Was looking for any other option if available. If no, we will have to follow the same what you told ! Thank you much @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Do we have any other approach instead of using "transform to a row per value"

Comment: Can we achieve this using SSIS packages if both the table1 data and table2 data is given in text file feed ! Like flat file comparison or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data is already loaded into Table_1 and Table_2, you can use the following function in a SELECT statement to identify the values with highest priority. The function accepts a string, splits it and returns the highest one based on priority in Table 2.
If you want to do this is SSIS, embed the SELECT in the Source component.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_GetPriority (@S varchar(max)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Split char(1),
        @X xml,
        @Output varchar(10)
DECLARE @Tab AS TABLE(Col1 varchar(50))

SELECT @Split = ','
SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@S,@Split,'</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ')

INSERT INTO @Tab
SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c) --AS T1

SELECT @Output = 
(SELECT T3.Col1 AS Col1
FROM Table_2 T3 
JOIN (
        SELECT MAX([Priority]) AS [Priority]
        FROM Table_2 T1 
        JOIN @Tab T2 
            ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
    ) AS T4
    ON T3.Priority = T4.Priority 
)

RETURN @Output
END
```

To insert into Table 3, use the following insert statement:

`INSERT INTO Table_3 ([S. No], Col1, Col2, Col3)`
   `SELECT [S. No], Col1, [dbo].[fn_GetPriority](Col2), Col3 FROM Table_1`

Comment: I have created an empty table called Table_3. Need the formatted data inserted into Table_3

Comment: after creating the function, use the following insert statement: INSERT INTO Table_3([S. No], Col1, Col2, Col3) 
SELECT [S. No], Col1, [dbo].[fn_GetPriority](Col2), Col3
FROM Table_1.

Comment: Getting error String or binary data would be truncated

Comment: Run the SELECT only (without the INSERT) and let me know if you have the error message: SELECT [S. No], Col1, [dbo].[fn_GetPriority](Col2), Col3 FROM Table_1

Comment: Okay it means you had the error because the columns in Table_3 were not  long enough. You can either increase the column lengths in the existing table or re-create it with:  SELECT [S. No], Col1, [dbo].[fn_GetPriority](Col2), Col3 INTO Table_3 FROM Table_1

Comment: @SSU if it worked fine you have to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: The script worked exactly, but i made a small change in the function, instead of SELECT MAX([Priority]), i modified it to SELECT MIN([Priority]) since it had to be sorted per lowest number being highest priority ! Thanks a ton ! @MayowaO . I have accepted the answer now